# Android - Google Map APIv2 in fragment shows only black sreen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have quite strange situation in my app code going on and maybe someone will be able to help me out with it. The problem is with Google Map included into it. Because of specification I have two different map implementations:

- MapActivity - extends `ActionBarActivity`
- MapFragment - extends `Fragment`

I am using `API 10`.

Both implementations are using this same map api key and this same layout.

In MapActivity everything is ok, map is showing and there is no error in LogCat. However, in MapFragment the situation is totally different.

I don't have map - to be more precise, map is black, I have Google logo at bottom left corner and zoom in/out controllers, but no map, just black screen and error in LogCat:

```
Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
```

This is the most important fragment of my MapFragment source code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkGooglePlayServices();
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("extra")) {
            setMarkers(getActivity().getIntent());
        } else {
            setMarkers();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Initialize map options.
        LatLng startPoz = new LatLng(52.34, 18.9);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startPoz, 6));
    }

    private void checkGooglePlayServices() {
        int status;
        status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(),
                    69);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
    }
```

and this is activity_map.xml (again - used in MapActivity and MapFragment):

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/include_map" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The extra view and import is added because without it the drawer each time was overlayed by map.

Also it is not a problem here, because I've tested it with only include_ma, so changing

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);
```

into

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inlude_map, container, false);
```

and this is the code of include_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:mapType="normal" />
```

Also, I've checked option with `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` and no change at all.

I think this is everything that I can tell about it. Hope, that someone can help me with that.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I am having the same issue at the moment and could use a helpful hint.

Comment: @user2145222 Sort of. It came out that the error was between Map and ZXing library to scan. What I did, I put ZXing into fragment as well, and now everything works great.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am not using ZXing so I must have created this problem some other way, nonetheless it's useful to know that for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get map using this line of code:

```
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

if you are using `SupportMapFragment` then you need to get it using the `SupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not working at all. Still this same problem.